# Accept everything until "more than 1 white space", using pyparsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyparsing

I have a file and parts of it looks like this:

```
string                     0            1           10
string with white space    0            10          30
string9 with number 9      10           20          50
string_ with underline     10           50          1
(string with parentese)    50           20          100
```

I need to parse each line, into something like:

```
[[string, 0 ,1 ,10], ....]
```

As you can see above, the first part can be pretty much anything, and the only way I can think of parsing this is to accept anything until I have 2 white space characters, then it is just numbers.

But I can not find this "UNTIL"-functionality in **pyparsing** doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code sample achieves what you want (with improvements over the previous version suggested by @PaulMcGuire):

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pyparsing import CharsNotIn, Group, LineEnd, OneOrMore, Word, ZeroOrMore
from pyparsing import delimitedList, nums 

SPACE_CHARS = ' \t'
word = CharsNotIn(SPACE_CHARS)
space = Word(SPACE_CHARS, exact=1)
label = delimitedList(word, delim=space, combine=True)
# an alternative contruction for 'label' could be:
# label = Combine(word + ZeroOrMore(space + word))
value = Word(nums)
line = label('label') + Group(OneOrMore(value))('values') + LineEnd().suppress()

text = """
string                     0            1           10
string with white space    0            10          30
string9 with number 9      10           20          50
string_ with underline     10           50          1
(string with parentese)    50           20          100
""".strip()

print('input text:\n', text, '\nparsed text:\n', sep='\n')
for line_tokens, start_location, end_location in line.scanString(text):
    print(line_tokens.dump())
```

giving the following output:

```
input text:

string                     0            1           10
string with white space    0            10          30
string9 with number 9      10           20          50
string_ with underline     10           50          1
(string with parentese)    50           20          100

parsed text:

['string', ['0', '1', '10']]
- label: string
- values: ['0', '1', '10']
['string with white space', ['0', '10', '30']]
- label: string with white space
- values: ['0', '10', '30']
['string9 with number 9', ['10', '20', '50']]
- label: string9 with number 9
- values: ['10', '20', '50']
['string_ with underline', ['10', '50', '1']]
- label: string_ with underline
- values: ['10', '50', '1']
['(string with parentese)', ['50', '20', '100']]
- label: (string with parentese)
- values: ['50', '20', '100']
```

The parsed values can be obtained as a dictionary with the first column (which was named `label` in the example above) as the key and the list of the remaining columns (named `values` above) as the values with the following `dict` comprehension:

```
{label: values.asList() for label, values in line.searchString(text)}
```

where `line` and `text` are the variables from the example above, generating the following result:

```
{'(string with parentese)': ['50', '20', '100'],
 'string': ['0', '1', '10'],
 'string with white space': ['0', '10', '30'],
 'string9 with number 9': ['10', '20', '50'],
 'string_ with underline': ['10', '50', '1']}
```

Comment: Nice answer, and well-explained! Just a couple of notes: IIRC, `CharsNotIn` is one of the few pyparsing classes that does *not* skip whitespace, so the `leaveWhitespace` call could be omitted (try it and see); I like the `Combine` construct, an equivalent could be done with `delimitedList(word, delim=space, combine=True)`, which will end up generating the exact same expression that you have done; the OP asked about some kind of UNTIL expression, pyparsing has `SkipTo`, which would look like `SkipTo(White(min=2))`. But these are just alternatives, your answer looks good to me.

Comment: Oh, one last point - it looks like the list of numbers only goes as far as the end of the line, but if the leading description of a line starts with a number, then that will get sucked into the number list of the previous line. We want `numbers` to stop at the line end, so you might add `numbers.setWhitespaceChars(' \t')`, and include a trailing `LineEnd()` in the definition of `line` so that you advance past it before building up the next description string.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcGuire! I have incorporated a number of your suggestions into what I think is an improved answer.

Comment: Ok, some last refinements and this will be a great pyparsing example. First, we might assume from the format that there is a label, always followed by 3 numbers, and we could get them from the parsed tokens as `line_tokens[0]` and `line_tokens[1:]`. But often you want to have some consistency in the output structure. Wrap `OneOrMore(numbers)` in a `Group`, which creates a sublist of the group's contents, as in `line = words + Group(OneOrMore(numbers)) + LineEnd().suppress()`. Now your parsed output will be `['string', ['0', '1', '10']], ['string with white space', ['0', '10', '30']], etc.`

Comment: And for the final step, add results names, which make your parser more robust and readable over time. Define line as 'line = words('label') + Group(OneOrMore(numbers))('values') + LineEnd().suppress()'. Now you can access the parsed elements by name, as `line_tokens.label` and `line_tokens.values`. Or print `line_tokens.dump()` to get a nice indented output of the tokens, with a bulletted list of the defined names and their values.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcGuire. I have incorporated your suggested improvements. This was my first time dabbling with _pyparsing_ and an excellent learning exercise. :)

Comment: @PedroRomano, this is indeed correct and thanks. I tried modify it to return a dic. but however I do it does not work? any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer to see if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, this one doesn't use `pyparsing`.

```
import re
lines   = re.compile("\r?\n").split(text)
pattern = re.compile("\s\s+")
for line in lines:
  print pattern.split(line)
#['string', '0', '1', '10']
#['string with white space', '0', '10', '30']
#['string9 with number 9', '10', '20', '50']
#['string_ with underline', '10', '50', '1']
#['(string with parentese)', '50', '20', '100']
```